# How to determine an available planetary communication window using orbital mechanics?

Tags: mars, artificial-satellite, communication

For class I have an orbit around Mars at an inclination of 63.4 deg and a base site of 55 deg North and was wondering how to work out the communication window, using orbital mechanics. 
Orbital parameters are: a = 20423.45km, e = 0.8, T = 24.62 hrs.
Any advice would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: In this question does Mars and the base rotate?

Comment: yeah they'll rotate with respect to time

Comment: Where is the station, in the Earth or in Mars?. Anyway, I find impossible to ask that question without longitude references for both the base (longitude) and the satellite (RAAN), Also note that your satellite is areosynchronous.